# How to make visible and invisible the layout of custom adapter based on the value set-ted in the custom adapter

Tags: android, android-custom-view, viewcontroller, android-cursoradapter, custom-adapter

In my application I have two layout in which the bottom layout some value will be null based on the user details from the server i want to make invisible the which are null, I am using the custom base adapter to create and set the value to the layout view text view please help in this issue. I have tried some google code its not working. 
my adapter class is as follows

```
public class SuggestionForumTopicAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<SuggestionTopicsModel> _suggestionlistData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    SuggestionTopicsModel suggestion_topics_model;
    private Context _context;
    RelativeLayout relative_layout;
    public SuggestionForumTopicAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<SuggestionTopicsModel> listData){
        _suggestionlistData = listData;
        _context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _suggestionlistData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _suggestionlistData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (layoutInflater == null)
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestion_custom_dispplay, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.suggestionPostName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggestionPostName);
            holder.totalnumberofsuggest = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalnumberofsuggest);
            holder.dateofcreate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateofcreate);
            holder.winnername=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.winner_name);

             relative_layout=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.winner_layout);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        suggestion_topics_model = (SuggestionTopicsModel) _suggestionlistData.get(position);

         holder.suggestionPostName.setText(suggestion_topics_model.getSuggestionText());

         //Log.i("inside adapter", suggestion_topics_model.getSuggestionText());

         holder.totalnumberofsuggest.setText(Integer.toString(suggestion_topics_model.getTopicsSuggestionCount()));

         //Log.i("inside adapter", suggestion_topics_model.getSuggestionTopicId());

         holder.dateofcreate.setText(suggestion_topics_model.getCreatedDate());


         Log.i("id", ""+suggestion_topics_model.getWinner());
         //Log.i("inside adapter", suggestion_topics_model.getCreatedDate());
        /* if (suggestion_topics_model.getWinner()==position) {
            relative_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            convertView.setClickable(false);
            }*/
         if (suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname()==null) {
             Log.i("name", suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname());
             relative_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
             holder.winnername.setText(suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname());
             relative_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             Log.i("name", suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder{

        TextView suggestionPostName;
        TextView totalnumberofsuggest;
        TextView dateofcreate;
        TextView winnername;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public class SuggestionForumTopicAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<SuggestionTopicsModel> _suggestionlistData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    SuggestionTopicsModel suggestion_topics_model;
    private Context _context;
    RelativeLayout relative_layout;
    public SuggestionForumTopicAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<SuggestionTopicsModel> listData){
        _suggestionlistData = listData;
        _context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _suggestionlistData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _suggestionlistData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (layoutInflater == null)
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestion_custom_dispplay, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.suggestionPostName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggestionPostName);
            holder.totalnumberofsuggest = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalnumberofsuggest);
            holder.dateofcreate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateofcreate);
            holder.winnername=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.winner_name);

            holder.relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.winner_layout);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        suggestion_topics_model = (SuggestionTopicsModel) _suggestionlistData.get(position);

         holder.suggestionPostName.setText(suggestion_topics_model.getSuggestionText());

         //Log.i("inside adapter", suggestion_topics_model.getSuggestionText());

         holder.totalnumberofsuggest.setText(Integer.toString(suggestion_topics_model.getTopicsSuggestionCount()));

         //Log.i("inside adapter", suggestion_topics_model.getSuggestionTopicId());

         holder.dateofcreate.setText(suggestion_topics_model.getCreatedDate());


         Log.i("id", ""+suggestion_topics_model.getWinner());
         //Log.i("inside adapter", suggestion_topics_model.getCreatedDate());
        /* if (suggestion_topics_model.getWinner()==position) {
            relative_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            convertView.setClickable(false);
            }*/
         if (suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname()==null) {
             Log.i("name", suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname());
             holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
             holder.winnername.setText(suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname());
             holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             Log.i("name", suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder{

        TextView suggestionPostName;
        TextView totalnumberofsuggest;
        TextView dateofcreate;
        TextView winnername;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is the same result

Comment: every time its going inside the else block how to avoid this

Comment: please try the amended code. It will be going into the else block for every row except for the first. It reuses the previous row to render the next, when it does that it passes in the previous convertView as an argument. This isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for the above problem i found a solution by just changing the following code

```
 if (suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname().contains("null")){
             Log.i("name inside the else ", suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname());
             holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{

             holder.winnername.setText(suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname());
             holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             Log.i("name", suggestion_topics_model.getDispplayname());

        }
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder{

        TextView suggestionPostName;
        TextView totalnumberofsuggest;
        TextView dateofcreate;
        TextView winnername;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    }
```